# What is the falloff function for the spot light blend value

Tags: lighting

The spot lamp has two cones: the inner cone where the light intensity stays constant and an outer cone where the inesity falls off. The size of the inner cone is controlled by the blend value, while that of the outer is controlled by the spot size.
My question is what is the falloff function for the light intensity between the two cones? Is it linear?

Comment: I would guess inverse square

Comment: I don't think it looks that sharp

Comment: Oh, eevee or cycles?

Comment: It looks the same to me in both engines

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html#spot-light):

> The falloff rate of the spot light is a ratio between the Blend and Size values; the larger the circular gap between the two, the more gradual the light fades between Blend and Size.

where Blend is

> proportional and represents that amount of space that the inner cone should occupy inside the outer cone Size.

and Size, as you say is the size of the Spot, in degrees.

To clarify, the light falls linearly from some value $x$ to 0 over the the distance between the inner circle and the outer circle.  The rate of fall is the ratio described in the manual.

Note: this assumes you are using the default settings, and not enabling nodes and creating a material.  You can change a lot of the behavior of a light in a material by setting falloff properties for example.

Comment: "the more gradual the light fades between Blend and Size." My question now is how gradual? As in a mathematical function.